# Showing $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int |f_n| - |f - f_n| = \int |f|$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I'm trying to show the following **without using the Dominated Convergence Theorem**:

> Let $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ measurable, and $\{f_n\}$ a sequence of integrable functions on $E$. Assume that $\sup \int_E |f_n| < \infty$ and $f_n \to f$ pointwise a.e. Show that
>
> $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_E \left(|f_n| - |f - f_n|\right) = \int_E |f|.$$

So far I have that:

Since $f_n \to f$ pointwise a.e. we have

$$
\begin{align}
\int_E |f| &= \int_E \liminf_{n \to \infty}\left(|f_n| - |f - f_n|\right) \\
&\leq \liminf_{n \to \infty} \int_E (|f_n| - |f - f_n|) \tag{By Fatou's Theorem} \\
&= \int_E |f_n| - \limsup_{n \to \infty} \int_E |f - f_n|.
\end{align}$$

I suppose I now need to show $\int_E |f| \geq \int_E |f_n| - \limsup_{n \to \infty} \int_E |f - f_n|$, but I am unsure how to proceed. Also, it's clear that $f$ is in $L^{1}(E)$ space, but I'm unsure if/how that is helpful either.

Comment: Fatou applies to sequences of non-negative functions, so at best you can do it for $\lvert \lvert f_n\rvert-\lvert f-f_n\rvert\rvert$.

Comment: @Gae. S. Ah, yes you are right. Thus, what I have so far is not valid.

Answer (score 3):

$||f_n|-|f_n-f|| \leq |f|$ so DCT can be applied.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. However, I'm looking for a way to prove this without the DCT.